# Running Test Groups in same class parallel

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

I am wondering if there is a way to run tests in the testng.xml file parallel, however the tests are found in only one class. The examples I have found show how you can do it in two classes, for example, running class ExampleClass1Tests and ExampleClass2Tests can easily be done by..

```
<classes>
    <class name="somePackage.ExampleClass1Tests"/>
    <class name="somePackage.ExampleClass2Tests"/>
</classes>
```

And this is very easy. But lets say I want to have just one class test seperate things. How can I

a) run these in parallel WebDrivers?
b) run these almost in a queue rather than parallel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need set attribute as parallel="tests" in your testng xml

```
<suite name="Parallel test runs" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
```

There is the “parallel” parameter. Set to “tests” because we want to run tests parallel. The other parameter is the “thread-count”. If it is set to 2, than two browsers will be opened and the first two tests will run from the list. If the thread-count is 5 than five browsers will be opened and all the five tests will executed parallel!

For tests your testng.xml structure should be like below:-

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Parallel test runs" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">

<test name="T_01">
    <classes>
        <class name="testNG.Parallel.Test01" ></class>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="T_02">
    <classes>
        <class name="testNG.Parallel.Test02" ></class>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="T_03">
    <classes>
        <class name="testNG.Parallel.Test03" ></class>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="T_04">
    <classes>
        <class name="testNG.Parallel.Test04" ></class>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="T_05">
    <classes>
        <class name="testNG.Parallel.Test05" ></class>
    </classes>
</test>

</suite>
```

If you want to run 2 classes parallelly

```
<suite name="Parallel test suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="2">
For classes your testng.xml structure should be like below:-

<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Parallel test suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="2">
  <test name="Test 1">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.parallel.TestParallelClassOne"/>
      <class name="com.parallel.TestParallelClassTwo"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Now the thing is you need to add both project classes in different packages in a same project and use my 1 example testng structure and add the attribute as above.

How to run two suites:-

```
<suite name="allSuites">
  <suite-files>
    <suite-file path="suite1.xml" />
    <suite-file path="suite2.xml" />
    ...
  </suite-files>
</suite>
```

Hope it will help you :)

Get back to me if still facing any issue :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `parallel=methods` in the testng xml file, if all tests are in same class.

In queue would mean sequential - if you have dependency between your tests then you need to add dependsOnMethods in your @Test annotations.  If not, you can just set `parallel=false` and that would run everything sequentially.